# Адаптивная верстка. Привязать блок к определенному участку картинки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте, попробую объяснить кратко. Например, имеется блок div под названием bg. Он растянут на всю длину и ширину экрана и залит какой-нибудь картинкой(например, комната 1200х768). Допустим такие стили:

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}
.bg{
  background: url("bg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width:100%;
}
```

На фоновой картинке имеется стол. Создаю блок div, который я хочу разместить на столе фонововой картинки. Возможно ли это реализовать? Т.е. просто ее туда поставить не проблема, но вот при изменении разрешения экрана он слетает(и указывание % в виде единицы измерения тут не помогает, он все равно слетает, ведь картинка уменьшается). Пока не понимаю в какую сторону копать. В итоге мне нужно привязать блок div к определенному участку картинки любым способом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Типа такого ? Наведите на подушку или на оба стула

```html
<!-- Image Map Generated by http://www.image-map.net/ -->
<img src="http://www.interiordesignlovers.com/images/interior_designs/kidroom/05/4-dearkids_290410_04.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
  <area target="" alt="подушка" title="подушка" href="" coords="695,372,669,376,665,389,679,397,712,401,747,396,754,381,730,369,721,370,707,369" shape="poly">
  <area target="" alt="стул" title="стул" href="" coords="731,497,689,503,677,508,689,557,702,577,691,604,678,633,704,651,736,652,769,648,747,582,765,557,771,529,773,512,762,507,752,504" shape="poly">
  <area target="" alt="второй стул" title="второй стул" href="" coords="803,494,833,489,866,492,890,496,890,512,878,550,870,564,893,623,846,627,804,614,817,584,827,563,810,538,799,509" shape="poly">
</map>
```

Comment: Отлично. То что нужно. Это открытие для меня. Осталось теперь сделать ее адаптивной. Еще минус этого способа то, что он не работает с фоном (только картинки).

Comment: я ссылку специально поставил , для удобства